# GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener is deprecated?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api-client

I get current latitude and longitude using GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks ,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener(is deprecated). what we use to get location instead of GoogleApiClient?

Java code here:

```
   private fun createGoogleApiClient(): GoogleApiClient? {
    return GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build()
}
override fun onConnected(p0: Bundle?) {

    if (!checkPermissions()) {

        requestPermissions()
    } else {
        val location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest) { location: Location? -> onLocationChanged(location) }



        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest) { location: Location? ->
                onLocationChanged(location)
            }
        } else {


        }
    }


}

   override fun onLocationChanged(p0: Location?) {

    if (p0 != null) {
        mCurrentLocation = p0
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

GoogleAPIClient is deprecated long back. For getting user's location you have to use fused location provider. Go through below link you will get an idea how to use it: -

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Comment: Not working means what? Did you tried with fused location?